# Need transfer effect with jquery dialog box open & close

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

i was looking for jquery dialog box open/close with transfer effect. i found one from this site and it is working. but it is not working the way i want.

### here is code

```
JQuery snippet
---------------
$("#PMinfo").dialog({

autoOpen: true,
height: 250,
width: 600,
modal: false,
draggable: false,
resizable: false,
close: function() {

    var $this = $(this);

    $this
        .dialog("widget")
        .effect("transfer", {

            to: "#smpb_info_btn",
            className: "ui-effects-transfer"

        }, 500, function() {

            $this.remove();

        });

}
```

});

```
CSS .ui-effects-transfer { border: 2px dotted gray; } 
---

HTML
----
<div id="PMinfo">Hello</div>
<button id="smpb_info_btn">Info</button>
```

i want the dialog should not open automatically rather when user click on info button then it should open with transfer effect as if it appear from button and position at center of the page. when user close then it close and move and disappear to info button.

so please guide me what i need to change to work it in my way. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use the jquery animate feature for this.

```
$(dialog).animate({'top':'20px','left':'20px', 'height':'20px', 'width':'100px'});
```

you have to provide the top & the left of the button as the input to the animate function so that it zooms into the button. The reverse could be done when user clicks on the button.

Comment: hi i am a beginner....can u please give full code instead of 1 line. which i can paste in my aspx page and test it. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to make it work, however it rather seems like an ugly hack. I'd be glad to see a more elegant solution than this:

```
var closing = false;

$("#PMinfo").dialog({

    close: function() {
        if (closing) return;
        closing = true;
        $(this)
            .dialog('open')
            .dialog("widget")
            .effect("transfer", {

                to: "#smpb_info_btn",
                className: "ui-effects-transfer"

            }, 500, function() {
                closing = false;
            })
        $(this).dialog('close');
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the problem you are seeing is the starting point of the transfer effect.  Your solution fixes it for IE but not for Firefox.  I've boiled the close down to the important part for you.  I hope someone posts something that crosses the browser boundary better.

```
        close: function() {
            $(this)
                .dialog('open')                    
                .effect("transfer", {
                     to: "#smpb_info_btn",
                     className: "ui-effects-transfer"
                   }, 500, function() {
                  //do something at the end of the transfer            
                })
            $(this).remove();
        }
```